# Spark 2.0 installation error in ambari version 2.2.1.1

Tags: apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am trying to install spark 2.0 through ambari (Version 2.2.1.1) using resource definition from

https://github.com/jerryshao/spark2-ambari-definition

While installing spark 2 thrift server got the following error. Can you please help.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-  services/SPARK2/2.0.0/package/scripts/spark_thrift_server.py", line 26, in <module>
 from resource_management.libraries.functions import stack_select
ImportError: cannot import name stack_select
```

Comment: Since now Spark 2.0 is officially released, does anyone has any updates on when can we see Ambari supporting spark 2.0 officially?

Answer (score 0):

The service definition you linked to is targeting HDP 2.5 which uses Ambari 2.4.x and not 2.2.x. This is evident partially by the fact that they're using `stack_select` instead of `hdp_select`. That function was renamed in Ambari 2.4.x and breaks backwards compatability since it's named `hdp_select` in prior versions.

HDP 2.5 ships with a technical preview of Spark 2.0.0 so there is no need for the service definition you linked. One is already provided in the HDP 2.5 stack.

IBM Open Platform (IOP) 4.3 (shipping sometime in 2017) will provide support for Spark 2.1.0. You can start using the [technical preview](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.3.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.welcome.doc/doc/welcome.html) of the IOP 4.3 stack now.